# There are no Libraries linked in iOS project of react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have tried to create a new project in react-native, After creating when I have opened the iOS project, in libraries folder I could not any libraries and i am not able to run the iOS Project.
I have tried **react-native run-ios** 
Got error like "error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AppName.xcodeproj."

[image: Image from iOS Project]

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Lis
2. cd AppName
3. open ios/AppName.xcodeproj inxcode and build.

react-native init AppName 
I have tried to create multiple projects, but still no luck of getting libraries

react-native info logs

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.5
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.5.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
    Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, by searching over SO and found a solution

In React-native 0.60 +, you need to install pods
Step1: cd ios
Step2: pod install
Step3: pod update

After completion you can run.